# flash and actionscript dead?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, programming-languages, actionscript-2

Hey I want to ask something more philosophical. I learned to code as2 when I was 13 later on I learned as3. Yes I wanted to do games. Today I'm way older and I have a question. Is actionscript development dead? Wasn't actionscript the API king of games as Kongregate and other portals claim?? In that case which is the flash subsitute?

Oh the link that triggered this question was the one below in which Scala, a new innovative and working experimental language is shown to be more used in all stats that my dear actionscript.

http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=projects&percent=true&l0=actionscript&l1=-1&l2=scala&l3=-1&commit=Update

Thnx for taking the time to answer

Comment: this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as the help states: **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions**. Scala is not an experimental language, and Flash and ActionScript are still in use on the web.

Comment: The question is subjective indeed? no, my descriptions are subjective. The question is objective "is flash death?" After that I give my context I can only talk about what I know. I can express myself as I want about languages and if im ill informed feel free to correct me, for me to learn... not to talk about flagging and stuff that helps nobody

Comment: [The plan is dropped](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1396021) I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash is not dead, but it is slowly being replaced by HTML5. The key word there, is slowly. All web developers will want some form of backwards compatibility and if you start going back to IE7, 8 or even 9, you'll find that HTML5 is unable to do a lot of what Flash can.

There is a reason massive companies such as Bet365, 888 and the majority of online game makers still use flash. Backwards compatibility is the primary reason.

http://isflashdeadyet.com/

Comment: Thnx a lot for your answer I ll check the link though you know somethng about the advantages of js and html5 over flash?? or the other way around??

Comment: dumb question your link contains it lol

Answer (score 2):

Just an opinion, of course: if you want to create a single code-base to get to iOS and Android, combined with an elegant way to program visually-intensive apps or games, I'd say AS3 ain't dead yet. If you code in something like FlashDevelop and do graphics in Flash; and if Adobe doesn't lose interest in the AIR platform, there's at least a few more years there.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your answer it is indeed useful