# function that detects if a ray is intersecting an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, stage3d

I have a function that detects if a ray is intersecting an object, but it works with a radius around the center of the object, I want it to work with a bounding box, I want to give it 2 Vector3D of the bounding box, and one vector of the origin of the ray and one of the direction of the ray, and it will calculate if there is an intersection, can anyone help me with that? what is the mathematical formula for this?

intersectRay(origin:Vector3D, dir:Vector3D):

Comment: Insufficient information. (1) Are you talking about 2D or 3D? (2) Even if it is simpler 2D case, bounding box is a rectangle (x,y,width,height), while ray is represented by origin point (x,y) and direction vector (x,y). If it is 3D, then bounding box should be (x,y,z,width,height,depth), and ray is origin (x,y,z) and direction (x,y,z) respectively.

Comment: You should stuff that function to your bounding box class. A 2D bounding box is not always axis-aligned (it can be turned, for example), with 3D there are 3 possible turns for a given 3D box. In case your boxes ARE all axis-aligned, then you have enough data to comprise a checker. There are some C++ implementations of such a check, find one, adapt and use. No exact formula, but 3 checks in XY, XZ and YZ with comparisons.

Comment: I'm talking about 3d, I want to create a bounding box as a simplification of the object, in 3DMax, the bounding box, will have 8 vectors  but they are not necessarily in a shape of a box, and I want to find a simple formula to send a ray from the camera with an origin and a direction and the formula will check if the ray is crossing within the bounding box or outside of it

Comment: truth is I need it in 2D, I want to calculate the hit using the angles, I'll find the most left point of the bounding box and the most right one and calculate the angle from the origin of the ray to both points, then I'll know the range of the angle which hits the target on the x axis, then I'll do the same on the y axis, I can't use too complicated math which I don't understand, I don't have too many objects on the scene and I only check on a sundown event. All I need is a function that will give me the degree between 2 points on the x axis and another degree on the y axis.

Comment: this way I'm projecting the 3D problem on a 2D plain, all I need to do now is find the external points, connect them with lines to make a closed shape, and see if the mouse picked a point inside the shape or outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
1. I use a bounding box of 8 points, each for each corner.
2. I used this function to give each point a location of x and y on a 2D plain this way I turned the 3D problem into a 2D problem, the x and y are really the horizontal angle of the point relative to the camera position and the vertical angle relative to the camera position point:

```
    public function AngleBetween2vectors(v1:Vector3D,v2:Vector3D):Point
    {
        var angleX:Number = Math.atan2(v1.x-v2.x,v1.z-v2.z);
        angleX = angleX*180/Math.PI;

        var angleY:Number = Math.atan2(v1.y-v2.y,v1.z-v2.z);
        angleY = angleY*180/Math.PI;

        return new Point(angleX,angleY);

    }
```

3. Then I use a convex hull algorithm to delete the point that are not part of the external outline polygon which marks the place of the object on the screen, can be found on the net, make sure the bounding box doesn't contain duplicate points like if you have a flat plain with no depth, this can cause problem for the algorithm, so when you create the bounding box clean them out.
4. Then I use this algorithm to determine if the point of the mouse click falls within this polygon or outside of it:

   ```
       private function pnpoly( A:Array,p:Point ):Boolean
   {
       var i:int;
       var j:int;
       var c:Boolean = false;
       for( i = 0, j = A.length-1; i < A.length; j = i++ ) {
           if( ( ( A[i].y > p.y ) != ( A[j].y > p.y ) ) &&
               ( p.x < ( A[j].x - A[i].x ) * ( p.y - A[i].y ) / ( A[j].y - A[i].y ) + A[i].x ) )
           {
               c = !c;
           }
       }
       return c;
   }
   ```
5. Then I measure the distance to the object and pick the closest one to the camera position, using this function:

   ```
       public function DistanceBetween2Vectors(v1:Vector3D,v2:Vector3D):Number
   {
       var a:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((v1.x-v2.x),2)+Math.pow((v1.y-v2.y),2));
       var b:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((v1.z-v2.z),2)+Math.pow((v1.y-v2.y),2));
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2));
   }
   ```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways, but this way is an interesting one, and it's good enough for me, I like it because it is intuitive, I don't like to work with abstract mathematics, it's very hard for me, and if there is a mistake, it's very hard to find it. If anyone has any suggestions on how I can make it more efficient, I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: Good answer. Surprised that people are still using flash for their games

Comment: Adobe Air is a cross platform SDK, why not use it? do you have anything better? with Air I create the app and then can publish it to any platform - PC, MAC, Android, iPhone, do you know of something else that gives you that?

Comment: Your tag says "flash" not Adobe Air. Flash don't run on mobile devices as native. You tagged flash and actionscript in your question and both of them are [dying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338232/flash-and-actionscript-dead) and will be gone soon. I think their support will be stopped soon. There are other options like Xamarin for apps and Unity for games. Again, I am not telling you what yo use, I am simply giving you heads up that what you are using will be discontinued very soon.

Comment: OK I didn't mean Flash player, I meant Flash the animation program which is now called Animate cc. Or Flash builder. Anyway I can do one app and then export it to all platform, smartphones and desktop, you don't tell me what to use, but I'm interested in knowing if there is some other tool that gives you the same features. "Xamarin for apps and Unity for games" are they good for publishing on all platforms? and are they really cross platform or are they just using the local browser object?